# Java задачка на логику

Tags: java

Возвращает true, если данное неотрицательное число на 1 или 2 меньше кратного 20. Так, например, 38 и 39 возвращают true, но 40 возвращает false.

---

less20 (18) → true

less20 (19) → true

less20 (20) → false

---

МОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ

```
public boolean less20(int n) {  
  if(20%n == 1 || 20%n == 2){
    return true;
  }
  if(n%20>0){
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

ИТОГ

```
    Ожидание       Вывод
less20(18)   → true  true   OK  
less20(19)   → true  true   OK  
less20(20)   → false false  OK  
less20(8)    → false false  OK  
less20(17)   → false false  OK  
less20(23)   → false false  OK  
less20(25)   → false false  OK  
less20(30)   → false false  OK  
less20(31)   → false false  OK  
less20(58)   → true  false  X   
less20(59)   → true  false  X   
less20(60)   → false false  OK  
less20(61)   → false false  OK  
less20(62)   → false false  OK  
less20(1017) → false false  OK  
less20(1018) → true  false  X   
less20(1019) → true  false  X   
less20(1020) → false false  OK  
less20(1021) → false false  OK  
less20(1022) → false false  OK  
less20(1023) → false false  OK  
less20(37)   → false false  OK  
other tests X
```

Comment: Непонятно, к чему тут эта картинка. Задача решается элементарно. `print(x % 20 >= 18)`.

Comment: Для того что-бы взять остаток от деления НА определенное число то вы должны делить именно на то число от которого хотите взять остаток. Например: 60 % 20 = 0. Тоесть 60 отстаток от деления на 20. Но не как не 20 % 60 = 20. Это уже противоположное тому что вам нужно. Ресурс для понимания что такое остаток от деления: https://math-prosto.ru/?page=pages/division_with_remainder/division_with_remainder.php

Answer (score 1):

`%` - это остаток от деления (`40%20` = `0`, `41%20` = `1`, `59%20` = `19`)

```
public boolean less20(int n) {
    return n < 20;
}
```

Comment: Имеет смысл поправить на 59%20=19. Я уверен, это была просто опечатка